# Why my buckets are "AWS Region" Not Found?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am using serverless Framework to deploy lambda function. Sometime it create S3 bucket with "AWS region" not found.

[image: screen shot]

I tried to empty or delete the Bucket, but it only shows bucket not found. What should I do?

Comment: Any more information if you hover over or click on that "not found"…?

Comment: it says `The bucket <bucket_name> was not found.`, so it's not about the region. in my case, that happened when I created the bucket with a different name in terraform, so the previous bucket was supposed to be removed. and it IS removed because if i click on bucket, the page shows the same error about the bucket not being found. probably the delete operation has not been propagated yet, to all nodes with bucket metadata, so the stale bucket names are still shown

Answer (score 2):

This is likely an indication that **you do not have permission** to retrieve the region of the bucket.

`s3:GetBucketLocation` permission is required to "return the Region that an Amazon S3 bucket resides in".

See: [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon S3 - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may be experiencing some lag.

***Amazon S3 is built on eventual consistency model, it can take some time for changes to propagate across all AWS Regions**. This is why you might temporarily see your bucket in the console, or in a response to a ListBuckets API request, even after you delete the bucket. Until the bucket is completely removed by Amazon S3, you might still see the bucket, but you can't perform any other actions on the bucket.*

As it states in this answer [here](https://repost.aws/questions/QUkvkbrOooTGKbFEV0dXsdFg/s3-bucket-not-found)